# Running multiple sidecars in Jenkins with docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am running a mysql sidecar like the following :

```
docker.image("mysql:5.6").withRun("-e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes -e", '--lower_case_table_names=1') { c ->
  docker.image("mysql:5.6").inside("--link ${c.id}:mysql") {

    /* Wait until MySQL service is up */
    sh "while ! mysqladmin ping -u root -h mysql -p ; do sleep 1; done"
    sh "mysql -u root -h mysql -p --batch -e 'show databases;'"
  }
  dockerRunArgs.add("--link ${c.id}:mysql")

  docker.build(image, dockerBuildArgs.join(' ')).inside(dockerRunArgs.join(' ')) {

    // the actual building, archiving, deployment, etc, stages go here
      withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'CREDENTIALID', variable: 'VARIABLE')]) {
        stage('Build') {
          sh 'chmod 777 ./build.sh'
          sh "./build.sh"
        }
        stage('DB migrations checkout ') {
          checkout([
            $class: 'GitSCM',
            branches: [[name: 'develop']],
            userRemoteConfigs: [[
              credentialsId: 'TOKEN',
              url: 'mygithuburl.git'
            ]]
          ])

          sh 'composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction --no-dev --no-progress'
          sh 'php artisan migrate:refresh --seed'
        }

      }
  } 
}
```

This is as shown in `Jenkins` documentation. Now I need to run some of the other services like `Redis, Elasticsearch, Memcached and Beanstalkd` . So where I need to add these docker images ?

Now I am building the docker image inside the `MySQL` docker image. Is it possible to run each of the container side cars in one stage and then do the migrations and run tests in next stage ?

Comment: Same problem here. I haven't found another solution than off-loading this to running docker compose, which will start containers as defined.

Comment: I have extended this and linked all the necessary services to the docker image I need and its working fine for me.